# Create Database Without Administrator privilege in Sql Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, database, sqlcmd, dml

As in my organization creating database is restricted and only I do have access for local server with windows authentication(no username and password). When I try to create a database at local server `@SSMS` and `@SqlCmd`. I'm getting error message as:

> CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.

Is there any chance to create a database at my local server? Any loopholes?

Note: I am not local administrator of my machine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I grant myself admin access to a local SQL Server instance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889334/how-do-i-grant-myself-admin-access-to-a-local-sql-server-instance)

Comment: @bmsqldev It works only if i am local administrator

Comment: You have to have the proper rights to create a new database... get those rights either from your Windows Administrator (for local admin) or your DBA.